# Process freezes when sharing context in RealSense

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, realsense

A process that initializes a Realsense pipeline periodically, freezes after a single cycle, when sharing context.
Here is a minimal recreating code:

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
from multiprocessing import Process

ctx = rs.context()


class RS:

    def __init__(self):
        print("init")
        pipe = rs.pipeline(ctx)
        print(pipe)


class Proc(Process):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Proc, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            print(i)
            RS()
            print("after")


vs = Proc()
vs.start()
```

If the context isn't shared, the code crashes after 337 cycles:

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
from multiprocessing import Process


class RS:

    def __init__(self):
        print("init")
        ctx = rs.context()
        pipe = rs.pipeline(ctx)
        print(pipe)


class Proc(Process):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Proc, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(400):
            print(i)
            RS()
            print("after")

vs = Proc()
vs.start()
```

When working with a thread instead of a process this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code snippet (when working with a global `ctx`), you initialise `ctx` in the main process, then create a new process which accesses that `ctx`.

In the second code snippet (`ctx` inside `__init__`), you initialise a new context in every loop iteration.

You need to combine the two: to initialise the context in the new process but only once. Something like that:

```
ctx = None

class RS:
    def __init__(self):
        global ctx
    
        if ctx is None:
            ctx = rs.context()

        print("init")
        pipe = rs.pipeline(ctx)
        print(pipe)
```